# Loading Images from external folder to component Angular 2

Tags: html, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-forms

I am trying to load my logo in my login.component.html but it can't seem to work. Here is how my folders are structured. I hope you can help me with this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8e8W.png)

[image]

Comment: can you post your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a css style to apply it to a div.

```
.logo {
    width: logowidthpx;
    height: logoheightpx;
    background-image: url('assets/img/logo.png');
}
```

and in your component

```
<div class="logo"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the base href in your index.html file looks like this:

```
<base href="/">
```

and then you should be able to access the assets folder like such:

```
<img src="assets/img/logo.png">
```

Also check your package.json file and make sure the assets folder is described properly in your project like such:

```
"projects": {
    "project-name": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico"
            ],
            ...
```

Also, some code snippets of what you are doing would be helpful as well. Please post any code of where you are trying to access the assets and any config info you think might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

in login.component.html

```html
<img src="./assets/img/logo.png">
```

thats it!

Comment: tried this, but it didn't work. I know this thing is right, I don't know what's wrong on mine, it seems to be not working

Comment: I always get this error  `ERROR in ./src/app/account/login/login.component.html
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './assets/img/logo.png' in 'c:\projects\new\proxiforms\client\src\app\account\login'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
<img src="src/assets/img/logo.png">
```

Comment: Can you explain further why you think that this solves the problem?

Comment: By giving full path or absolute path, it might solve the problem. @NicoHaase

Comment: And why does your code snippet only contain a relative path when a absolute path might be better?